# Batch Rename Script

Tags: batch, batch-rename

I have been trying all morning to try to write a simple batch rename script.  This is my first time trying this sort of thing.  I have been trying to use `For /R` so that my command recurses through subfolders but it is not working.

My code looks like this:
    `FOR /R %%a in (.) do REN "i.JPG" "inlet.JPG"`

`REN` is working in the parent directory, but not recursing through subdirectories.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to add the `/d` option in `for` if you want to match directories. Also, you need to use `"%%a\i.JPG"` in the `ren` command source file name.

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed the filename and added the `%%a`.  This seemed to solve the problem.  What do you mean match directories?

Comment: By default `for` matches files, not directories, unless you add `/d`: see `for /?` for more details.

Comment: Further investigation shows that `.` will be matched without `/d` - I don't fully understand why. What `%%a\i.JPG` expands to is `SubDirName\.\i.JPG`. A neater solution is `FOR /R %%a in (i.JPG) do REN "%%a" "inlet.JPG"`: this avoids errors on subdirectories with no `i.JPG` file in them, especially if you want to rerun the batch file.

Comment: @eyerah Can you specify what you really want to do with batch file? Is there only a single file or many file with same name?

Comment: I've always linked using the `FOR /F` and then putting the `DIR /S` commands to do the `REN` commands if doing so recursively—just a personal preference I suppose but always works very well for me.

Comment: Thanks all for the thoughtful comments and welcoming vibes. @Biswapriyo

I just wanted a script to rename photos that I had previously sorted through and added simple codes (i.e., "i").  In sub directory there were many files, but no files with the same name twice.